# What CSS code would make the left sidebar content float right?

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-float

EDIT: I'm not asking about alternative ways to solve this problem, although I appreciate the thoughts that have been presented so far. I'm looking for a way to make the left sidebar content float right instead of left. Just like it does when I enter "float: right;" in #RecoWidgetLarge with "inspect element" in google chrome.

This is driving me crazy. No matter what CSS code I use I cant make the customer testimonials box (in the left sidebar - reco.se), `float right` instead of `left`.

The current `left-float` gives me problems when the window is resized or when the webpage is visited through an iPad. So I figured if the left sidebar content floats right, this problem will go away..

Here's the page I'm working on [www.allfemaleevent.com](http://www.allfemaleevent.com/), try resizing to see what I'm talkning about.

I've inspected the element and tried a lot of CSS editing, two examples below:

```
.recoWidgetLarge {
  float: right;
}
```

OR

```
div.textwidget  {
  float: right;
}
```

Nothings working, seems like something is blocking those commands or something. Any ideas?

Comment: It's not going to go away with the floats you have. The content of div is set to a specific width with the containing div is dynamic, that's why you are getting overlap.

Comment: To me it seems like on that particular width you might want to stack the columns instead of floating them, so try taking off the floats and set the widths to 100%.

Comment: When I set the float to right instead of left with "inspect element" in google chrome I get the desired behaviour, I just cant get style.css to the same thing with my example code above. I must be doing something wrong? The right sidebar (facebook social) is wider then the specified width and the abundance "sticks out" more to the right then the big slider at the top of the page does since it floats left. I wanna do the same thing for the left sidebar except I wanna let the abundance "stick out" more to the left by floating it right. I hope you can understand my poor english skills? Thanks!

Comment: Stevo: they are beeing stacked at iPhone width, but using iPad the float right idea would look better. I just don't know what to write in style.css the make it happen..

Comment: Nobody with any idea on how to make the float: right work like it does when #RecoWidgetLarge is set to float right inside of google chromes "inspect element"? There must be something wrong in my style.css edits?